# How can I manage entities implementing a common interface?

Tags: typeorm

I know that I can `implement` an [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) when defining an `Entity`, but I want to be able to treat all implementations of this interface as if they had a shared table, with a common `Repository`. To better illustrate my problem, here a **two examples**:

### GitHub repository owners

On GitHub both users and organizations can own repositories. Let's imagine there is a `User` and an `Organization` entity. They both implement the `RepositoryOwner` interface that specifies stuff like an array of `Repository`'s as a relation.

Now take a look at GitHub's ["Trending developers" page](https://github.com/trending/developers). It treats `User`'s and `Organization`'s equally as if there was a common `Repository<RepositoryOwner>` that could be used to fetch the data.

### Resource sharing site

A site where users can upload different types of resources like images, videos and documents. All of these types have their own `Entity` with different properties, but all of them implement the `Resource` interface. On a user's profile page there's a list of all the resources uploaded by this user. A `Repository<Resource>` would be very helpful again, the type of a resource is determined using `typeof` and displayed using an icon.

Comment: Can you simplify your question a bit? What do you want to achieve? I don't seem to follow...

Comment: @RajshriMohanKS What part wasn't clear enough? I'd love to improve the question but don't know how.

Comment: I'm assuming that you intend to share a common table from which you want to derive two more tables? In that case why can you not define an interface `IRepositoryOwner` and `implement` it in a base entity `RepositoryOwner`. And then `extend` `RepositoryOwner` to `Organization` and `User` entities? Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Does this allow me to retrieve an array of `RepositoryOwner`'s, check the type using `repositoryOwner instanceof User` and cast `repositoryOwner` to a `User` when needed?

Comment: You should be able to retrieve an array of `RepositoryOwner`s but `repositoryOwner instanceof User` would be false. And casting `repositoryOwner` to `User` would not be possible. You'd be missing the derived class properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you intend to share a common table from which you want to derive two more tables? In that case you can define an interface `IRepositoryOwner` and implement it in a base entity `RepositoryOwner`. And then extend `RepositoryOwner` to `Organization` and `User` entities.

This would allow you to retrieve an array of `RepositoryOwners` but `repositoryOwner instanceof User` would be false. And casting `repositoryOwner` to `User` would not be possible. You'd be missing the derived class properties.